# Running database function in controller..how do I transfer to Model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Okay, I have a function in my controller that works. However, I shouldn't be calling the database in the controller (as we all know). I normally can easily migrate information from a model into a controller, but I'm having a hard time with this one. I won't even share my model version...how would you write this to a model?

```
    $this -> db -> select('title, price, number_sites, number_entries, white_label'); 
    $query = $this -> db -> get('pricing', 3); // limit 3 rows

    $row1 = $query->row(0); // 0 grabs first row in table: Package 1        
    $data['row1'] = $row1;

    $row2 = $query->row(1); // 1 grabs second row in table: Package 2        
    $data['row2'] = $row2;

    $row3 = $query->row(2); // 2 grabs third row in table: Package 3        
    $data['row3'] = $row3;
```

Comment: Exactly like you write it for a controller...but in a model. Everything it's well explained in the manual

Comment: Wouldn't this bit need to be in the controller? Since it's using a $data array - that's attached to a view... `$row1 = $query->row(0); // 0 grabs first row in table: Package 1        
    $data['row1'] = $row1;`

Comment: WHo said that $data is "attached to a view"? You can name variables however you like and wherever you like. Read the manual, but _cum grano salis_ , don't take it so pedantically ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy and paste it into the model in a function you want to call:

```
function dbstuff(){
    $this -> db -> select('title, price, number_sites, number_entries, white_label'); 
    $query = $this -> db -> get('pricing', 3); // limit 3 rows

    $row1 = $query->row(0); // 0 grabs first row in table: Package 1        
    $data['row1'] = $row1;

    $row2 = $query->row(1); // 1 grabs second row in table: Package 2        
    $data['row2'] = $row2;

    $row3 = $query->row(2); // 2 grabs third row in table: Package 3        
    $data['row3'] = $row3;
    return $data;
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$this->load->model('MyModel');
$data=$this->MyModel->dbstuff();
$this->load->view('view',$data);
```

Comment: Works...but prevents other $data variables I'm sending to the view...any idea to the cause of this?

Comment: try merging the existing data variables with array_merge: `$data=array_merge($data,$this->MyModel->dbstuff());`

Comment: What would this be doing exactly? Is `$data=array_merge($data,$this->MyModel->dbstuff());` the same as `$data=$this->MyModel->dbstuff();` but adds to existing $data variables?

Comment: Yup.  Combines the array returned from the model to the existing data array.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a model class that includes an static method for wrapping the  query to select from the database and returns the instances of the model class.

For example:

```
class MyModelClass {

// Your class code here

static function findByPricing($price){

    $output = array();

   //run your query here using your db handler

   foreach($resultingrows as $row){

       $object = new MyModelClass();
       $object->setAttributeOne($row['attribute_one');
       $object->setAttributeTwo($row['attribute_two');
       $object->setAttributeThree($row['attribute_three');

       $output[] = $object;

   }

   return $output;

}


}
```

Then from your controller just do:

```
 $objects = MyModelClass::findByPricing(3);
```

Comment: Why this approach? Why not just $this->load->model('myodel'); $this->mymodel->method(), as it's usually and regularly done in CI?

Comment: This is an object oriented approach, for me is cleaner. Notice that you have to call more than one line of code to load "$this->load->model('myodel'); $this->mymodel->method()". With my approach you only call one line and that line will do everything "from loading the model, run the query and returns the model instances". I think is more cleaner, elegant, readable and flexible. Is an object oriented approach.

Comment: Well, even the one I suggested is an "object oriented approach", and is the one used by CI throughout the whole framework; also, your model doesn't extends the parent CI_Model, so won't have access to the CI superobject. Do you regularly write model like this when using codeigniter?

Comment: Ok, i agree with you. Is just a matter of taste. I prefer to go with my approach for the reasons i explained on the previous comment.

Comment: I got you now. The thing is that you are thinking in the code-igniter way. Well if you are  using that framework you can keep your approach just to be consistent with the framework. But personally i prefer mine, is the way zend works. But, yes for consistency purposes is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to consult the documentation first.

User Guide for [Models](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

Once you have the information for writing model classes, create one and put this function in it.

```
public function getPricing(){
  return  $this -> db -> select('title, price, number_sites, number_entries, white_label') -> get('pricing', 3) -> result_array();
}
```

Comment: I know how to write models dude...you didn't get my question. ;)